# how to get a column based on a index in python?

Tags: python, indexing

I have a .csv file that I extracted as a matrix called "k":

```
>>> k
array([[  0.  ,   0.  ,   5.  ,  10.  ,  15.  ,  20.  ,  25.  ,  26.  ,
         27.  ,  28.  ,  29.  ,  30.  ,  31.  ,  32.  ,  33.  ,  34.  ,
         35.  ,  36.  ,  37.  ,  38.  ,  39.  ,  40.  ,  41.  ,  42.  ,
         43.  ,  44.  ,  45.  ,  46.  ,  47.  ,  48.  ,  49.  ,  50.  ,
         -5.  , -10.  , -15.  , -20.  , -25.  , -30.  , -35.  , -40.  ,
        -42.  , -44.  , -46.  , -48.  , -50.  ],
       [  1.  ,   1.04,   1.02,   1.  ,   0.97,   0.95,   0.93,   0.92,
          0.92,   0.91,   0.91,   0.9 ,   0.9 ,   0.89,   0.88,   0.88,
          0.87,   0.87,   0.86,   0.85,   0.85,   0.84,   0.83,   0.82,
          0.81,   0.81,   0.8 ,   0.79,   0.77,   0.76,   0.75,   0.74,
          1.06,   1.08,   1.12,   1.14,   1.17,   1.2 ,   1.23,   1.27,
          1.28,   1.3 ,   1.32,   1.34,   1.37]
```

Then I want to extract all the values in a column which shoud have LAT as the first value. I tried with this code but it extracted the wrong column. Can somebody help me?

```
LAT = 42

k = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter = ';', filling_values = 0)

extractedData = k[:,LAT]
```

Comment: I'm guessing 42 is not the column you want. There is no minimal working example here, so it's hard to answer. Have you tried `LAT = 41`?

Comment: @rpoleski thank you for your help. I modified the answer and I inserted a part of my matrix k. As you can see in the first row i have some values. I defined LAT = 42 because i want to index the matrix k based on it and extract the whole column which has 42 in the first row. I hope I'm a bit more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
k[:, k[0] == LAT]
```

`k[0] == LAT` makes a mask that selects the column, which has value `LAT` in first row. If you replace it with `LAT` then you get LAT-th column.